# Http client getting status() in retries is broken

Tags: php, laravel

#### Laravel Version

10.35.0

#### PHP Version

8.1.26

#### Database Driver & Version

Mysql 5.7

#### Description

When using the [retries](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#retries) feature of the Http client, attempting to get the `status` from the response as per the docs throws an error and I'm unable to get the response status code.

#### Steps To Reproduce

1. Make a get request anywhere to a domain that doesn't exist via the Http client
2. Implement the `retries` function like this:

```php
$client = $client->retry(3, 100, function (Exception $exception, PendingRequest $request) {
    Log::debug('foo');
    Log::debug($exception->response->status()); // <-- this line is erroring
    Log::debug('bar'); // <-- I never make it here

    return true;
});
```

Observe the error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException::$response

Also, I see my **foo** log but never the **bar** log.

Either the docs is wrong, or getting the response is broken. The domain I used deliberately is one that hangs, which is intentional: sdfsd.com

Comment: _"The domain I used deliberately is one that hangs, which is intentional: sdfsd.com"_ - and by "hang", you mean what exactly? I am getting a response page from godaddy, telling me this domain was for sale. Possible though, that your attempt gets a different response, than a browser would. But a ConnectionException probably means it never go so far, that you got any actual HTTP response.

Comment: According to the documentation, "response" is part of `Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException` while you're actually getting a ConnectionException. And you just skipped the check `$exception instanceof RequestException`, which is also documented.

Comment: The docs has: `$exception->response`, this is coming from `Exception $exception`, which is coming from `use Exception;`